# SVG external graphic fails in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, style, svg

I'm using Geoserver 2.6.2. I need to use a SVG file as an external graphic to style a points layer. When I open the WMS layer in QGIS, the points are not displayed. This is not happening if I use a PNG file.

Here is an extract of my SLD code:

```
<PointSymbolizer>
  <Graphic>
    <ExternalGraphic>
      <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://myserver/img/c_3_3_8.svg"/>
      <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
    </ExternalGraphic>
    <Size>40</Size>
  </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

I'm wondering why the image format has to be `svg+xml`.

Is an additional XML file needed?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably a little too late but for the sake of posterity...

An SVG is an XML-based format. I think this is all that it refers to. You can open an SVG in a text editor and it will have an XML structure.

Although why it doesn't display in this case isn't clear. I presume it can't access the file. There could a number of reasons for that.